# How to rename a txt file using Java after copying contents from another txt file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have created a program where there is a file called groups.txt. This file contains a list of names. To delete a group, it has to exist within the file. I used the Scanner method to search through each line for the name. If it contains the line, it sets val as 1. Which triggers the val == 1 condition. What I wanted to do during this block, is try to delete groupName from the groups.txt file. To do this, I created a new txt file called TempFile which copies all the names from groups.txt EXCEPT groupName. This file is then renamed to groups.txt and the old groups.txt file is deleted.

Everything works as intended, except the renaming. The temp.txt file still exists and the groups.txt file is unchanged. I checked the boolean success, and it always returns as false. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
 if (method.equals("delete group")){
                int val = 0;
                String groupName = myClient.readLine();

                try {
                    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("groups.txt"));

                    while (file.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = file.nextLine();

                        if (line.indexOf(groupName) != -1){

                                val = 1;    
                        } 
                    }
                     if (val == 1){

                                try {

                                    File groupFile = new File("groups.txt");
                                    File tempFile = new File("temp.txt");

                                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(groupFile));
                                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

                                    String currentLine;
                                    System.out.println(groupName);
                                    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){

                                        String trimLine = currentLine.trim();

                                        if (trimLine.equals(groupName)){
                                             continue;
                                        } else {
                                            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    writer.close();
                                    reader.close();
                                    groupFile.delete();
                                    boolean success = tempFile.renameTo("groups.txt");

                                } catch (IOException f){
                                    System.err.println("File Not Found: " + f.getMessage());
                                }                       }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException f){
                    System.err.println("File Not Found Exception: " + f.getMessage());
                }

            }
```

---

CODE BEFORE THE ABOVE:

```
 if (command.equals("group")){
            String method = myClient.readLine();

            if (method.equals("create group")){

                String groupName = myClient.readLine();

                int val = 0;

                try {
                    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("groups.txt"));

                    while (file.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = file.nextLine();
                        if (line.indexOf(groupName) != -1){
                            Report.error("group name already exists, please pick another");
                            val = 1;                                
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException f){
                    System.err.println("File Not Found: " + f.getMessage());
                }

                if (val == 0){
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("groups.txt", true));
                        out.println(groupName);
                        out.close();

                    } catch (IOException e){
                        Report.error("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

In the second part of the code, this is where I originally update the groups.txt file. So every time the user adds a group, it updates the groups.txt file by adding the new groupName to the end of the file. First, I make sure the groupName doesn't already exist using Scanner. myClient is a BufferedReader which reads from another class which stores what the user types in the command line.

Comment: check the return value of `groupFile.delete()`

Comment: The value returns false :(

Comment: Actually, @HappyHal might be onto something by mentioning to close the Scanner which is opening `groups.txt`

Comment: Same issue when I close scanner right after I close my BufferedReader & BufferedWriter. Unless I'm placing it in the wrong place?

Comment: Could you post the whole code?

Comment: @assassinweed2 I tested separately, if the command is **delete** your codes work fine on my ubuntu eclipse.

Comment: @HappyHal so it must be an issue with my computer then hmmm. I have Windows and I created both files within the same folder. My java code is within the same folder too. So I'm assuming it's not an issue with the file path or the read only files. Everything works as intended until the delete and rename part.

Comment: @assassinweed2 Well, I still suggest you set a breakpoint at delete() line to check everything... It may be your computer issue, but it's higher probability that you missed something... What if after create command you forgot to close the stream then do delete command? Since I only tested the delete command.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an external editor keeping the file open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also do not forget to close **Scanner**. First you should make delete() work and make sure you know your current working directory, and write your filepath relative to it. Check with:

```
File file = new File("abc.txt");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

One thing might be unrelated, also check your environment because

> In the Unix'esque O/S's you cannot renameTo() across file systems. This behavior is different than the Unix "mv" command. When crossing file systems mv does a copy and delete which is what you'll have to do if this is the case. The same thing would happen on Windows if you tried to renameTo a different drive, i.e. C: -> D:

Comment: delete() returns false. I'm using Windows and both files are stored within the exact same folder, along with all my .java code.   Everything is copying to the correct txt files. The only issue is just deleting the old file and renaming the new file. With closing scanner, I tried doing that straight after where I close my BufferedReader and BufferedWriter and the issue remains.

Comment: Sorry, I just editted my comment to include that, I forgot to mention that I tried it. I closed scanner straight after where I closed my BufferedReader and BufferWriter. No progress :(

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm not sure what you mean, can you please expand

Comment: If it is Read Only for example you will not be able to delete it

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ah no, I created both files so I don't believe that's the issue since I'm still able to edit them etc.

Comment: try closing the Scanner before `File groupFile = new File("groups.txt");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat same error , I tried placing it after the while statement too, and that didn't work. Perhaps scanner isn't the issue?

Comment: *Perhaps scanner isn't the issue?*  it is looking that way

Comment: Close **Scanner** before you created groupFile, then try first close reader then close writer. It seems if the file exists, it's always issues related to streams not correctly closed or perimission not allowed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat & HappyHal same issue... I think it might be because when I first created groups.txt, I used the PrintWriter method. I'm thinking that might have caused the issue? Is that possible?

Comment: @assassinweed2 Yes, make sure you have to close every related things about that file before you try to delete().

Comment: @HappyHal Just realised I didn't close Scanner AFTER creating the file. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: @ScaryWombat Just solved the issue, I didn't close Scanner AFTER creating the file. Thank you!